# Heroku with python- Unable to push application due to error module

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, heroku

I am trying to create an application with python and I would like to deploy it to Heroku. It works well on local server but whenever I try to publish it it says that he is not able to find the called packages( can't find Pandas and Numpy). I do not think that the problem is the requirement file but anyway I'll paste it here.

```
astroid==2.3.3
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
entrypoints==0.3
flake8==3.7.9
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
joblib==0.14.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
pylint==2.4.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
scikit-learn==0.22.2
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
sklearn==0.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
typed-ast==1.4.1
Werkzeug==1.0.0
wrapt==1.11.2
```

and the error is simply:

```
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
#and same for numpy
```

Do you guys have any solution for that? Obviously I have tried the standard options like: pip(3) install..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a different Python version and so is Heroku. You then try to install Python libraries that are available for your current Python version but it is not available on Heroku.

You can specify a Python version on Heroku through `runtime.txt`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

You can check your current Python version with: `python3 -V`. (your `python3` might be called `py`, `py3` or `python` in the terminal)

Before putting your python version into that `runtime.txt` make sure Heroku is supporting that Python version. If not upgrade your Python version and make sure it is working locally before deploying to Heroku again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Thin. Was very helpful!